# How to quickly jump to the class declaration line in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, ideavim

Suppose a `Foo.java` file which defines the `Foo` class.

The cursor is now on some line of `Foo.java`. *The symbol under the cursor is not necessarily `Foo`*).

How to quickly jump to the class declaration line (i.e., the line like `public class Foo {`) in Intellij?

Any shortcuts for this?

---

I use the [`ideavim`](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) plugin. Therefore, solutions relying on vim functionalities are OK.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html ?

Comment: @PhilipRollins I am afraid that `Ctrl + B` is not applicable in this situation. `Ctrl + B` requires that the symbol under the cursor now is `Foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Mac you can do cmd + up arrow 
(on Windows or Linux, I'm assuming it will be ctrl + up arrow)

This will select the current file in the breadcrumb (navigation bar) then hit enter and you'll be at the class declaration

You can look to which key combination this is mapped for you by looking in the keymaps for 'Jump to Navigation Bar'

[image: Jump to Navigation Bar]

Comment: Thanks. It is `Alt + Home (Jump to Navigation Bar)` for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: ok, jetbrains reference card says that Alt + Home should just show the Navigation Bar https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: Yes, Alt+Home for me on the Mac as well. The only thing to remember is the home button on the Mac is `fn + left arrow`. So, the key combination for Alt+Home is `alt + fn + left arrow`. This takes the cursor to the navigation bar. Then you have got to press enter to take the cursor to the class declaration line.

Answer (score 1):

From 2022.3.1 on Mac, cmd + up may not work for this case. it need you jump to  a specific method.

Instead of cmd + up using navigation bar, **cmd + F12** which show the file structure popup, then use `left arrow` to select class name if method is selected default, press enter and you'll be navigated to class declaration line.